# Replace specific elements

Tags: bash, awk

I am very new to coding things.I have been trying to replace specific elements for days.

```
 1 2 3 4 5

 1 2 3 4 5

 1 2 3 4 5

 1 2 7 4 5

 1 2 7 4 5
```

First want to find lines that have 7 in 3rd column.
Then if the line has 7, want to replace 3rd column in two above the line to 0.

```
 for ((i=n1;i<n1+5;i++))
 do
 n2=`grep -n "$i" test.txt | cut -d ':' -f1`
 let n3=$n2{print $3}
 awk 'n3==7 (n2-2){print $3=0}' 
 done test < test1
```

I have totally no idea, need your help.
Thanks

Comment: Is that a school asignment? ^^

Comment: What exactly have you been doing all these days? You should have spent some of that time studying the `awk` manual.

Comment: `awk '$3 == 7{$3 = 0} 1' file`

Comment: What do you mean by "replace 3rd column in two above the line"? Can you edit your question to show the expected output for your sample input?

Comment: @anubhava's suggestion is the right way to do this, without all the extra code. Just a single line and done. What awk is doing: "If the 3rd field of the current record is equal to 7, then set the 3rd field to 0 and print the line back out"

Comment: give a try to my answer. Is this what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the number of fields is always 5, otherwise adapt the script.

Give a try to this:

```
awk '$3=="7" && NR>2{b[3,1+NR%2]="0"}
NR>2{i=1+NR%2;print b[1,i],b[2,i],b[3,i],b[4,i],b[5,i]}
{i=1+NR%2;for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) b[j,i]=$j}
END {for (i=1;i<=2;i++) print b[1,i],b[2,i],b[3,i],b[4,i],b[5,i]}' text.txt
```

There is an exellent tutorial to start with [Awk - A Tutorial and Introduction - by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

This above `awk` script is using a two-dimensional array (`b[f,l]` buffer) to store the fields of the 2 previous lines.

Each line of the script follow `pattern {commands}`.

`NR` is the record (line) number. `1+NR%2` is alternatively equals to `1` and `2`.

`$3=="7" && NR>2{b[3,1+NR%2]="0"}`: The 3rd field of the record (line) NR-2 is reseted to zero when current 3rd field is equals to `7`.

`NR>2{i=1+NR%2;print b[1,i],b[2,i],b[3,i],b[4,i],b[5,i]}`: The fields of the record (line) NR-2 stored in the buffer are printed starting from record numer 3.

`{i=1+NR%2;for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) b[j,i]=$j}`: the fields of the current record (line) are saved into the buffer.

`END {for (i=1;i<=2;i++) print b[1,i],b[2,i],b[3,i],b[4,i],b[5,i]}`: when `awk` reaches the end of the file, there are still 2 lines in the buffer;  they are printed.

The Test:

```
$ cat text.txt
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 7 4 5
1 2 7 4 5
$ awk '$3=="7" && NR>2{b[3,1+NR%2]="0"}
NR>2{i=1+NR%2;print b[1,i],b[2,i],b[3,i],b[4,i],b[5,i]}
{i=1+NR%2;for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) b[j,i]=$j}
END {for (i=1;i<=2;i++) print b[1,i],b[2,i],b[3,i],b[4,i],b[5,i]}' text.txt
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 0 4 5
1 2 0 4 5
1 2 7 4 5
1 2 7 4 5
```